# Repeating operations vs multilevel queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was always bothered by how should I approach those, which solution is better. I guess the sample code should explain it better.

Lets imagine we have a table that has 3 columns:

- (int)Id
- (nvarchar)Name
- (int)Value

I want to get the basic columns plus a number of calculations on the `Value` column, but with each of the calculation being based on a previous one, In other words something like this:

```
SELECT
    *,
    Value + 10 AS NewValue1,
    Value / NewValue1 AS SomeOtherValue,
    (Value + NewValue1 + SomeOtherValue) / 10 AS YetAnotherValue
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    Name LIKE "A%"
```

Obviously this will not work. `NewValue1`, `SomeOtherValue` and `YetAnotherValue` are on the same level in the query so they can't refer to each other in the calculations.

I know of two ways to write queries that will give me the desired result. The first one involves repeating the calculations.

```
SELECT
    *,
    Value + 10 AS NewValue1,
    Value / (Value + 10) AS SomeOtherValue,
    (Value + (Value + 10) + (Value / (Value + 10))) / 10 AS YetAnotherValue
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    Name LIKE "A%"
```

The other one involves constructing a multilevel query like this:

```
SELECT
    t2.*,
    (t2.Value + t2.NewValue1 + t2.SomeOtherValue) / 10 AS YetAnotherValue
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t1.*,
        t1.Value / t1.NewValue1 AS SomeOtherValue
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            Value + 10 AS NewValue1
        FROM
            MyTable
        WHERE
            Name LIKE "A%"
    ) t1
) t2
```

But which one is the right way to approach the problem or simply "better"?

P.S. Yes, I know that "better" or even "good" solution isn't always the same thing in SQL and will depend on many factors.

Comment: Obviously the first one is the better approach as it would not need temporary table via subquery to recalculate. And besides you have two subqueries there compared to none on the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tired a number of different combination of calculations in both variants. They always produced the same execution plan, so it could be assumed that there is no difference in the performance aspect. From the code usability perspective the first approach i obviously better as the code is more readable and compact.

Comment: This is an interesting insight. Checking if execution plans differ and if not, stick to the one that is more readable.

Comment: I'm accepting this because of mentioning the same execution plan. However it should be noted that even if queries produce the same execution plan the execution time can differ in a reproducible way (ie. one query always executes slightly faster than the other). Those differences are usually very minor, but if a query is really complex it might be more visible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "right" way to write such queries.  SQL Server, as with most databases (MySQL being a notable exception), does not create intermediate tables for each subquery.  Instead, it optimizes the query as a whole and often moves all the calculations for the expressions into a single processing node.

The reason that column aliases cannot be re-used at the same level goes to the ANSI standard definition.  In particular, nothing in the standard specifies the order of evaluation for the individual expressions.  Without knowing the order, SQL cannot guarantee that the variable is defined before evaluated.

I often write multi-level queries -- either using subqueries or CTEs -- to make queries more readable and more maintainable.  But then again, I will also copy logic from one variable to the other because it is expedient.  In my opinion, this is something that the writer of the query needs to decide on, taking into account whether the query is part of the code for a system that needs to be maintained, local coding standards, whether the query is likely to be modified, and similar considerations.